# SSIS Package - DNS contains architecture mismatch

Tags: c#, ssis, odbc, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2019

I've created an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2019 targeting SQL Server 2019. There is a C# Script Task that attempts to connect to two potential 32-bit ODBC data sources. If either are available, it returns the name of the connection which is then passed into the Connection Manager via a Property Expression (Name = @[User::DataSourceName]). When running the package in VS, everything works as expected, with Run64BitRuntime set to True and False.

After I deploy it to the 2019 SQL Server and run it, I get the error:

*ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application*

for both connections, with Run64BitRuntime set to True and False.

What is the "*Application*" referred to in the error message and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

"Application" refers to SQL Server. Since you want to connect to a 32-bit ODBC data source, please try to download and install [sqlserver32-bit ODBC](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2239080), and establish a corresponding ODBC connection, and then in Create a data source in Visual Studio to use the recently created ODBC.

Comment: Thanks. We will install this and see what happens!

Comment: We have not installed this recommended driver as I noticed that yesterday the package ran successfully without this error when invoked from an external PowerShell script. When I run the package from SSMS, that is when I see the error I mentioned in my initial post. I am really confused as to why that matters...

Comment: @JoeFoster Sounds like what happened to [this post](https://sqljotter.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/test-connection-failed-error-im014-mysql-driver-error-with-ssrs/). According to it, it is still because the corresponding driver is not installed on the management tool. Of course, you can also refer to other steps in this post